# how to display 3 random pictures out of 8 using bash

Tags: bash, random, echo

I have **8** images in a directory.

the path is `/blabla.com/img.`

I need to access this path and **choose 3 out of 8 randomly** and display those.

`If 3 pics are the same`, it should `echo "yeeey"`.

`Otherwise`, `"neeey"` and record these responses in a text file.

Comment: are your 8 images all different?

Comment: only 3 of them are the same which makes it harder to get 3 in the row.

Comment: looks like an assignment question

Comment: filenames in an array and look at a loop with `RANDOM % 8`. You can loop until you get 3 separate filenames (array indexes).

Comment: I have to agree with sharuzzan: This is fishy question.  More like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to do your homework for you!
However I can give you some insight:

- store your 8 file names in an array
- call `$RANDOM % 8` 3 times and store the value in 3 index variables
- use the 3 index variables to extract your 3 files
- use `sha256sum`, `sha512sum` or `md5sum` to compute the signature of your images and store the result in 3 variables
- compare the values of the 3 variables if they are the same `echo "yeeey"` else `echo "neeey"`
- if on top of that you want to display the picture as written in your post you could call `eog` or other similar tool with the finename as parameter and of course in background, with a `&` at the end of the command call.

Good luck with your assignment and let me know if you need help!

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your help !

Answer (score 0):

let's array an array of distinct elements (for example 8):

```
array=({A..H})
```

(1) use `RANDOM` special variable modulo the number of elements to get a random number between 0 and number-1 inclusive

```
number=$((RANDOM%${#array[@]}))
```

the first random element is

```
first=${array[number]}
```

remove the element from array and reassign the array to reindex without gap (`declare -p array` to see)

```
unset array[number]
array=("${array[@]}")
```

restart from (1)

Comment: hi...Thanks for this

Comment: if I'm using for loop, and N=3, it gonna be something like this? for((i=0;i<N && ${#a[@]};++i)); do